# Как сравнить значение в двух хешах?

Tags: ruby

```
cart = [
{ type: :soccer_ball, qty: 2 },
{ type: :tennis_ball, qty: 3 }
]

inventory = {
soccer_ball: { available: 3, price_per_item: 100 },
tennis_ball: { available: 5, price_per_item: 30 },
golf_ball: { available: 5, price_per_item: 5 }
}
socer_qty = cart[0][:qty]
tennis_qty = cart[1][:qty]
socer_price = inventory[:soccer_ball][:price_per_item]
tennis_price = inventory[:tennis_ball][:price_per_item]
yy = inventory[:tennis_ball][:available]
zz = inventory[:soccer_ball][:available]
if zz >= socer_qty && yy >= tennis_qty
total = socer_qty * socer_price + tennis_qty * tennis_price
else 
puts " tovara net na sklade"
end

p total
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Этот код выводит общий вес всех мячей. Но мячей для тенниса больше tennis: 3 чем их наличие на складе available: 1.  Как сделать сравнение?

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Обращаетесь к нужному элементу хэша по ключу, берёте значение, сравниваете

Comment: @Василиса Спасибо, вроде работает, но пришлось делать много переменных. Не знаю правильно это или нет?

Comment: @AlexIlichev сложно сказать, правильно ли это, не видя вашего кода

Comment: @Василиса изменил код

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение очень помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий, но даже с тремя позициями в `inventory` уже сложно читаемый. И совершенно не масштабируемый - представьте себе, что появилась хотя бы сотня позиций...

Всё станет гораздо проще, если просто перебрать содержимое корзины и выяснить для каждого товара, есть ли он на складе в нужном количестве, и сколько он стоит.

```
def handle_order
  total_price = 0

  cart.each do |item|
    item_type = item[:type]

    return "Not enough #{item_type} items in stock" if item[:qty] > inventory[item_type][:available]

    total_price += (item[:qty] * inventory[item_type][:price_per_item])
  end

  "Total price for your cart: #{total_price}"
end
```